# c# key generation method with String type, and int length arguments used to generate a key for encryption

Tags: c#, string, key, int, generator

I'm not looking for any code samples from anyone here, just want to know if you guys know anything about how to do this, or of any articles related to this subject that you can link me to. I hope this is a good question, I am working on a project and have am very stuck. If it is any help, the type needs to accept Random, Public, or Private. If Random it will randomly choose between public or private key style.

```csharp
public void Generate(String type, int length)
{
    // All generation code here obviously. :3
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for *specific* questions that actually have answers. "Does anyone know anything about this?" is not specific enough to have an answer.

Comment: Wait so asking if anyone has an answer regarding how to write a generating method that accepts two arguments, a string named type and an integer named length. I mean the question cannot get more specific, does anyone know good documentation to help me finish my project regarding the topic of generating specific type and length encryption keys.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If Random it will randomly choose between public or private key style.

That sounds just weird, as if this is a toy instead of something useful. (I can't think of any serious application where "either a public or private key" is acceptable.)

However, for the purpose of generating public/private key pairs (and they should be pairs, as far as I know) you could start from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273.aspx

In particular, you could use something like

```
//Generate a public/private key pair.
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
```